# Notifications at preset intervals

Tags: c#, windows, service, notifications, schedule

I need to develop an application in C # that will from time to time to access a database for information to notify the user desktop.
The idea is that the user can define the number of days , hours or minutes that he wants to receive these notifications.

Someone suggests some way to do this type of application .

I thought of creating a service on windows , but do not know how to make the service start notifications at defined times .

Answer (score 0):

This sample demonstrates a service which uses a timer to do stuff. It's exactly what you're looking for: [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx).